# Typescript error when trying to map over Enum keys to produce JSX elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, enums, mapping

For the life of my I can't figure this one out.

I have a simple enum, here:

```
export enum depositTypes {
  ACH = 42,
  Wire = 36,
  Check = 3,
  Credit = 2,
}
```

I want to map to option tags for a select, i.e.:

```
Object.keys(depositTypes).map((enumKey: keyof typeof depositTypes) => <option key={depositTypes.enumKey} label={enumKey} value={depositTypes.enumKey} />)
```

I get an error:

> Argument of type '(enumKey: "ACH" | "Wire" | "Check" | "Credit") => JSX.Element' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number, array: string[]) => Element'.
>     Types of parameters 'enumKey' and 'value' are incompatible.
>       Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"ACH" | "Wire" | "Check" | "Credit"'.

Any ideas?

Comment: You'd think this would be low-hanging fruit and yet we've resigned ourselves to using a ts-ignore.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are applying your assertion at the wrong place.  `Object.keys(depositTypes)` is an array of `string` so its `.map` callback needs to be a function that can accept any `string`.  Right now you have a mapper that can only accept keys of your `enum`, so it cannot be used to map `string[]`.

Instead, we need to say that *the array itself* is an array of keys of your `enum`.

```
(Object.keys(depositTypes) as (keyof typeof depositTypes)[]).map( ... )
```

If you find yourself doing this a lot, you might want to extract it into a function:

```
const typedKeys = <T extends {}>(object: T): (keyof T)[] => {
  return Object.keys(object) as (keyof T)[];
}
```

```
typedKeys(depositTypes).map( ... )
```

There's an error in the code that you didn't spot earlier because of the previous error.  You are using `depositTypes.enumKey` which is looking for the literal key `'enumKey'` rather than `depositTypes[enumKey]` which looks for the key of this current variable.  You want this:

```
(Object.keys(depositTypes) as (keyof typeof depositTypes)[]).map(
  enumKey => <option key={depositTypes[enumKey]} label={enumKey} value={depositTypes[enumKey]} />
)
```

Comment: Apologize for not seeing this sooner because it's such an old question, but yes, this is what I eventually did and it is absolutely the correct answer. Can't type the element in the callback function when mapping over an array that isn't explicitly-typed yet. I thought there might be some sort of leeway or type-inference of the array since I'm explicitly saying which type of element each thing in the array should be, but that isn't how TypeScript works! I appreciate you and it should help others who stumble upon this too. I'd only been working with typescript about 6 months lol.